# How to create an ArrayList of arrays of primitives

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, primitive

This may sound confusing, but I'd like to make an ArrayList which contains int[]. Would an int[] be considered an object, or is it treated the same way as a primitive and require wrapping and unwrapping the values. For example:

```
ArrayList<int[]> intArrays = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

The reason I use an ArrayList is I'd like it does not have a set amount of members, and has an unknown amount of max values. Therefore, an int[][] wouldn't work. I just need to know if the above is valid.

Comment: Yes, the above is syntatically valid.  Arrays are objects, hence you can pass in a primitive array as a generic parameter.

Comment: An array is an object.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to implement the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this no problem. The following compiles fine:

```
    ArrayList<int[]> x = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    x.add(new int[10]);
```

`int[]` is an object and you can do with it everything you can do with an object, including getting the class name (`Class a = int[].class`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have an `ArrayList` which contains `int[]` elements.
An `int[]` is an `Object`. So yes, you can do this.

```
int[] x = {1,2,3};
System.out.println(x instanceof Object);
```

Comment: An int[] is an object? Array of anything is an object.

Comment: @P.K普 Yes, I know. That's a generalization of my statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> intArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have an ArrayList which contains arrays which are objects too.

```
ArrayList<int[]> intArrays = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int[] arr = { 1,2,3 };
intArrays.add(arr);
```

> Every array has an associated Class object, shared with all other arrays with the same component type. The direct superclass of an array type is Object.

You can find more about Arrays here: [Arrays - Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` which is a wrapper class for the int primitive type or you can use  an array of `int[]` which an object